# Application crash immediately when deploy to iPhone running iOS 12 from Xcode 10

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios12

App submitted to store one year ago. It worked fine up to iOS 11 but in iOS 12 the app is immediately crashing even without launching. I tried to debug the issue but I couldn't, because before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, the app crashes and I did not find any error logs.

It is happening in iOS 12 only, working fine with below iOS 12.

How can I debug this issue?

Comment: So the build you made for SDK iOS 11 is crashing in SDK iOS 12 before it enters to didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ? Where you see this ? Or its crashing while debugging ? Is it happening for a lot of users ? There are a lot of questions actually to get what is happening...

Comment: Xcode debug navigator should be able to tell you at least something.

Comment: @quant24: please don't use code formatting (`\``) for highlighting or otherwise mark up things that are not code. This messes with screen readers and thus affects accessibility of the site. Thanks!

Comment: How could an app crashes if it isn't launching? No crashing logs even with `Device Logs`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly installed your XCode Update? Sometimes you have to install cli 
 (that is needed e.g. by mtouch if XCode links your assemblies) or other components by hand.

Are you're credentials (certificate) still valid? or otherwise asked: did you build another app since this happens?

Have you set a breakpoint right in you app delegate and step throw until the app crashes? Can you show logs? If you don't have some, than create them by yourself. Do exception handling and log the exceptions. Or otherwise said: More information please.